# wpf targetting version 4.0 from 3.5 affects IDataErrorInfo implementation

Tags: wpf, idataerrorinfo

I've an MVVM application implementing IDataErrorInfo using version 3.5. I want to try and target 4.0 so have amended the Target Framework setting and changed a few bits around (BitmapFrames and the like). Most things seem just fine and the process was relatively painless, until I noticed that the implentation of IDataErrorInfo has been affected.

My control template for validation looks like this:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="temp__">
    <Border BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">    
        <DockPanel>         
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                         Width="16" Height="16" Margin="-20,0,0,0" 
                         Source="{StaticResource ErrorIcon}" 
                         ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=adornedElement, 
                                             Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors), 
                                             Converter={helper:ValidationErrorsToStringConverter}}"/>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="adornedElement"/>
    </DockPanel>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

and is used in a textbox style like this:

```
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource error_holder}">
```

In my ViewModel, GetValidationError(string propertyName) uses a switch to validate the appropriate property based on my rules.

The issue is that once a validation has been fired it does not update. For instance, a field can be set as required or not. When loaded, the fields that are required are marked as invalid with an appropriate message. Previously, when a value was entered that was still invalid the error message in the tooltip would update. However this no longer works and the error message still remains as a null value message.

Does anyone know of any changes in the implementation of IDataErrorInfo in 4.0 that may account for this? Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've sort of fixed this. Rather than use the default implementation that uses Validation.Errors[0] which gives binding errors when the error is fixed, I'd used a converter. Not sure why this resulted in the behaviour originally described, but it did. So I originally changed back to using Validation.Errors[0] and the error message updated correctly. However, this would result in the binding errors returning. Instead I implemented the advice here [prevent binding errors](http://blog.spencen.com/2008/10/11/validation-template-without-binding-errors.aspx) and the issue is resolved.

My ControlTemplate now looks like this:

```
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="temp__">
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
  <Border BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Border.Effect>
      <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Orange" BlurRadius="10" />
    </Border.Effect>
    <DockPanel>          
      <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Width="16" Height="16" Margin="-20,0,0,0" 
                         Source="{DynamicResource ErrorIcon}"               
             ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=adornedElement, 
                               Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent}"/>
      <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="adornedElement"/>
    </DockPanel>        
  </Border>
</DockPanel>
```

However, where previously a required field was flagged as an error on loading, this no longer happens. The validation only appears once another error has occurred due to user input. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

i cant see your binding but you should add ValidatesOnDataErrors.

Comment: My binding looks like this: <TextBox Text="{Binding ShortTitle, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>. As I said, this all worked fine before moving on to 4.0